# Drawing 2D graph in Android

Tags: android, gdi+

I want to do a porting of my GDI+ application built in C# for Windows in Android. The app draw 2D graphics of the math equation. What object I have to use to minimize the time for rewriting the code?
I have read about the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) objects implements some method like DrawLine, DrawShape... Is the best way?

Comment: Use a library, such as [aChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/)

Comment: If you want to port your code to Android, then yes, you use the Canvas with the DrawXXX functions